# Vuetify button with loader with text inline

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use loader inside button along with text. I've modified example from vuetify documentation:

```
 <span slot="loader">
   <v-icon light class="custom-loader">cached</v-icon> 
    Loading...
 </span>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/olegef/pen/mjROZo)

On click event button text changes and loader appears. However button's content is not inline.

[image]

Please advise how to make button content composed inline and independent of text width?

Comment: does it you need? by remove `display: flex;` inside `.custom-loader`?

Comment: @Sphinx yes, it makes content inline but only in case of short text inside button. I need to fit text in slot longer than initial button text

Answer (score 2):

DEMO: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejgEoO

I've added styles for the classes used by vuetify: `.v-btn__loading` and `.v-btn--loader .v-btn__content`: So your CSS becomes:

```css
.v-btn__loading {
  position: relative;
}

.v-btn--loader .v-btn__content {
  display: none;
}

.custom-loader {
  animation: loader 1s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes loader {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes loader {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```